# SQL Server 2012 : recover lost symmetrical encryption key or just disable encryption

Tags: sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2012, dynamics-crm-2013, recovery

We currently face a huge problem and we hope you can help us.

We have two systems (Dynamics CRM 2013) on two different servers, both use SQL Server 2012.

One on our dev server the other on our live server. The dev instance is simply a recovery from a backup of our live system which has encryption enabled.

Unfortunately the vm of our live system crashed horribly and there's no way to recover the system. However we still have our backups of course.

But here comes the problem - We restored the backup from yesterday but it just won't accept our password. So we can't take control over the encryption feature and also can't disable it anymore. So we assume the key got changed or lost.

When we try it on our dev server it still works as it should, but unfortunately it's already some months old, so we can't just use a copy of that system.

Is there any way to recover an encryption key or somehow disable the encryption again (even if we lose some data)?

Comment: Commiserations. Unfortunately this question is off topic here. I won't add to your misery by voting down, but I have to close the question, try serverfault instead.

Comment: Oh alright, sorry. I gonna move it.